# How to get my external jar in executable jar's classpath in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have added to my pom.xml a  section that specifies the mainClass and allows it to essentially create an executable jar.  I have included a bunch of dependencies that maven manages as well.  It compiles, and if I run the program with no options, it executes fine, displaying usage information.  However, if I actually pass in the parameters, it fails and says NoClassDefFoundError: com/sas/isd/midasapi/ParticipantDetailExt, which is in a jar I included as an external jar.  I am confused that it compiled and runs to show usage information, but it fails to find the class after as the ParticipantDetailExt is a class that is imported.  Wouldn't it identify that it was not found during compiling?  How do I get it so that my on jar with ParticipantDetailExt is seen when I run my exectutable jar?  Is there a classpath thing or pom thing I need to do in addition to the adding jar as external jar?

Comment: Is there a checkbox in the eclipse build path settings for that jar that says export? There used to be. It should be on one of the tabs.

Comment: I see something for export.  What do they mean by export?  Note that if I manually copy com/sas/isd folder to target/classes my program works.  Does export essentially do the same?  I was actually surprised that another project's classes folder was in that target/classes folder along with the project's java class.

Comment: Note that what i see is an Order and Export tab.  However, it looks like all you can do do is move up and down the few things in there, but you cannot add anything.

Comment: To clarify, I unjared the jar that has ParticipantDetailExt, which created com/sas/isd/midasapi folder with all the classes and then copied that to target/classes folder.  However, a clean will I suspect just wipe that away, so this is not ideal.  I need to know the magic gui way to do this or simply just add the jar, skipping the unjaring process.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are running mvn clean package or mvn clean install to create your jar.By default the jar created by a maven project does not include dependencies in that jar.

Option 1# create a jar-with-dependencies, see: [How can I create an executable JAR with dependencies using Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven).

Option 2# If you are just looking to copy dependencies to a lib folder see: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html